# How to find incompatible references in a solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've inherited a giant solution with lots of projects.  Each of these projects references a good number of old school DLL assemblies, Nuget packages, etc...  Some of the references are of different versions.  For instance, I got Newtonsoft.Json v8.x, 9.x, 10.x.  So as you can imagine the build generates a myriad of warnings and the web.config files have a ton of binding redirects.

I really want to clean all this up.  Is there a way for Visual Studio (or some other tool) to identify same references that are from different versions?

Comment: Try ResolveuUR https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=battas.ResolveUR-ResolveUnusedReferences that might help.

Comment: [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/index.html) may be of use to you. It allows you to have a single source of defined package versions to be used across all of the projects in your solution.

Comment: @GokulE So far ResolveUR has pegged one of the CPUs for a couple of minutes and now it's just sitting there blocking Visual Studio.  It might be confused by all the competing versions of references.  The very thing I am trying to fix :)

Comment: @devNull That's actually is what I need.  I might take it on after everything is cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the NuGet packages you can use Consolidate in Visual Studio.
Right-click on the solution and choose 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...'.

With 'Install' the latest version will be installed in all the selected projects.

[image]